# How to sort rectangles from left to right in multiple rows?

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting

I have a set of rectangles that im getting from a process which I draw on another image. These rectangles are stored in a list which is not sorted. So I sort then by x and then by y like this:

```
      rect1 = rect1.OrderBy(p => p.X).ThenBy(p => p.Y).ToList();
```

But its not giving the sorting I want, it starts with 0 on bottom >> 1 on top >> 2 on bottom >> 3 on top....... like in this image below :

[image: img]

How to sort this to get the first line to be 0-13 and second line  to be 14 to 27

**Solution:**

**Sorting result suggested by Dmitry worked perfectly.**

[image]

Comment: Order by Y and then by X, assuming Y=0 is at the TOP.  If Y=0 is at the bottom, order by Y descending and then by X.

Comment: Tried that, Y = 0 is at the Top, since characters are not perfectly aligned in Y, it sorts in incorrectly.

Comment: `rect1 = rect1.OrderBy(p => p.Y>thr).ThenBy(p => p.X).ToList();`  where thr is a threshold value that separates the two rows. This will work if you only have 2 rows, for more rows you will have to preprocess y and round the values in a way that all y in a row have the same value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, you want to sort first by `Y` (top line first, then 2nd line etc.) and then by `X` (from left to right). The problem is that rectangles are *not aligned perfectly* and `Y` can slightly *vary* (e.g.
rectangle #19 is a bit higher than rectange #21) and we can't just naively sort by `Y` (#19 will be the first in such an order).
So far so good we should *define* "on the same line" and order by "lines" and then by `X` within each line.

Let definition "**on the same line**" be

> rectangles `A` and `B` are on the same line if `Abs(A.Y - B.Y) < B.Height`

If we can use such definition the code can be:

**Code:**

```
private static IEnumerable<Rectangle> OrderByLines(IEnumerable<Rectangle> source) {
  var line = new LinkedList<Rectangle>();

  foreach (var item in source.OrderBy(r => r.Y))
    if (line.Count == 0 || (item.Y - line.Last.Value.Y) < item.Height)
      line.AddLast(item);
    else {
      foreach (var rect in line.OrderBy(rc => rc.X))
        yield return rect;

      line.Clear();
      line.AddLast(item);
    }

    foreach (var rect in line.OrderBy(rc => rc.X))
      yield return rect;
}
```

then

```
rect1 = OrderByLines(rect1).ToList();
```

**Demo:**

```
Random random = new Random(123); // seed to be reproducible

int width = 30;
int height = 50;
int interline = 20;
int dy = 10;
int dx = 5;

Rectangle[] demo = Enumerable
  .Range(0, 2)
  .SelectMany(row => Enumerable
     .Range(0, 10)
     .Select(col => new Rectangle(
        col * width + random.Next(-dx, dx),
        row * (height + interline) + random.Next(-dy, dy),
        width + random.Next(-dx, dx),
        height + random.Next(-dy, dy))))
  .ToArray();

var result = OrderByLines(demo)
  .ToList();

Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

**Output:**

```
{X=4,Y=8,Width=32,Height=56}
{X=32,Y=-10,Width=25,Height=42}
{X=56,Y=2,Width=34,Height=49}
{X=86,Y=-1,Width=25,Height=56}
{X=120,Y=-5,Width=25,Height=58}
{X=146,Y=-10,Width=32,Height=40}
{X=182,Y=2,Width=31,Height=57}
{X=210,Y=-8,Width=30,Height=57}
{X=242,Y=-9,Width=30,Height=41}
{X=274,Y=-6,Width=29,Height=55}
{X=4,Y=77,Width=29,Height=43}   <- second line starts
{X=32,Y=62,Width=26,Height=47}
{X=56,Y=69,Width=32,Height=43}
{X=85,Y=70,Width=33,Height=59}
{X=116,Y=74,Width=25,Height=42}
{X=148,Y=62,Width=31,Height=41}
{X=175,Y=61,Width=32,Height=42}
{X=213,Y=79,Width=34,Height=47}
{X=243,Y=64,Width=25,Height=45}
{X=270,Y=71,Width=27,Height=52}
```

Comment: Hi Dmitry , I noticed a small issue today. When we use the . (dot) special characters the sorting is disturbed. How to modify the code to include dot in it?

Comment: @Alisha: we should exploit the same principle: to define *on the same line* and then sort characters within each line. If we have *small* rectangles for punctuations like `.`, `"` then `Abs(A.Y - B.Y) < B.Height` can be *too restricting* since `B.Height` is too small. You can try experimenting with intersection e.g. `B.Y >= A.Y && B.Y <= (A.Y + A.Y + A.Height) || B.Y + B.Height >= A.Y && B.Y + B.Height <= (A.Y + A.Y + A.Height)` here we define "on same line" if rectangle's projections on Y intersect.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, I tried it, intersection condition also gives the same result.

Comment: This is the condition I used -  if (line.Count == 0 || line.Last.Value.Y >= item.Y && line.Last.Value.Y <= (item.Y + item.Y + item.Height) || line.Last.Value.Y + line.Last.Value.Height >= item.Y && line.Last.Value.Y + line.Last.Value.Height <= (item.Y + item.Y + item.Height))